# Update vertex buffer in non UI thread using DirectX11

Tags: directx-11

I want to render a object with a dynamic vertex buffer and I do rendering in UI thread. I am thinking is it possible to change this vertex buffer content in a non UI thread using Map and Unmap.

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Direct3D 11 multi-threading model is fairly simple:

- Calls to the `ID3D11Device` are thread-safe (unless you used the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED` flag when you created the device). You can call the methods on this interface from any thread.
- Calls to the `ID3D11DeviceContext11` are *not* thread-safe, and you should only call methods on this interface for a given context from a single thread at a time.

This is why `Map` and `Unmap` are part of the `ID3D11DeviceContext11` rather than `ID3D11Device` or on the `ID3D11Resource` itself like it was in Direct3D 10. The operation is inherently serial with other operations.

This means you should have a single thread using the immediate device context (and DXGI), and this should probably be the same thread as your main windows message pump (for the reasons covered in [DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI): Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025.aspx).

You could `Map` on the same thread as the one using the immediate context, marshal the pointer to another thread, and then `Unmap` it from the original thread when that thread completes but this is highly unlikely to improve performance.

See [Introduction to Multithreading in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891.aspx)